# Sammy - arbitrary number of path parts?

Tags: sammy.js

I have a set of cascading dropdowns where the value in one defines the options for the next. For various reasons, it makes more sense for my application to represent this in the url path than url args. So I want urls like

```
mysite/#/Supermarkets/Produce/Apples
```

Where `Supermarkets` is not a dropdown but `Produce` and `Apples` are. The trick is that I don't know ahead of time that the path hash has three parts; the first part always exists, but  the fact that there are two (or three or one or zero) dropdowns is only known after the first `/Supermarkets/` part of the path resolves.

I'm not sure how to set this up with sammy. Does it even support this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a route with parameters.  The parameters then are accessed by the params object.  I tried the code below which worked for me:

```
var app = $.sammy('header', function () {

    //this allows us to use the sammy templates
    this.use('Template');

    //load header template
    this.get('/Supermarkets/:type/:item', function (context) {
        alert(this.params['type']);
        alert(this.params['item']);
    });


});
$(document).ready(function (){
    app.run();
});
```

So now if the url is /Supermarkets/Produce/Apples I will get two alerts one for the type parameter which is Produce and one for the item parameter which returns Apples.

Comment: but what if your url is `/Supermarkets/Produce/Apples/Macintosh/`. As I specified in the question - the whole thing is not knowing how many parts the route will have.

Comment: Oh ok - this may be what you are looking for:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876112/sammyjs-optional-parameters