# Sammy js optional parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ajax for paging so Sammy.js is great choice. But I'm also using checkboxes which filters results. This is ok for Sammy: I have to define route which Sammy will intercept. Problem is :I don't want some filters(parameters) to show on URL if they are not checked but Sammy does not support optional parameters.

```
    var samm = $.sammy(function () {

        this.defaultCheckFormSubmission = this._checkFormSubmission;
        this._checkFormSubmission = function (form) {
            var $form, path, verb;
            $form = $(form);
            path = $form.attr("action");
            verb = this._getFormVerb($form);
            var index = path.indexOf("#");
            if (verb === "get" && path.indexOf("#") == -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return this.defaultCheckFormSubmission(form);
            }
        };
        this.get('#/Page=:page', function (context) {

            alert("sammy");
        });
    });
    samm.run('#');
```

I don't want all my URLs look like www.something.com#/Page=5%Filter1=0?Filter2=0?Filter3=0?Filter4=1...........

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want Sammy to handle extra filters (like unchecked checkbox values), just don't put them in your route.  Instead just grab the parameters from the controls via jquery and do the ajax request like that.  So Something like this:

```
this.get('#/Page=:page', function (context) {
        var page = this.params['page'];
        var filter1 = $("#chkFilter1").is(':checked');
        var filter2 = $("#chkFilter2").is(':checked');
        var filter3 = $("#chkFilter3").is(':checked');
        //etc..
        //do work here
    });
```

If you need the URL to be different for deep linking or google tracking and you know the max number of variables you need, then you can plan out your routes for the amount of variables you have.  You must put the most variables first, because otherwise Sammy will match the URLs incorrectly.  This is how you would make the URL only show checked values but still grab the unchecked values via JQuery:

```
   this.get('#/Page=:page%filter1=:filter1?filter2=:filter2?filter3=:filter3', function (context) {
        var page = this.params['page'];
        var filter1 = this.params['filter1'];
        var filter2 = this.params['filter2'];
        var filter3 = this.params['filter3'];
    });
    this.get('#/Page=:page%filter1=:filter1?filter2=:filter', function (context) {
        var page = this.params['page'];
        var filter1 = this.params['filter1'];
        var filter2 = this.params['filter2'];
        var filter3 = $("#chkFilter1").is(':checked');
    });
    this.get('#/Page=:page%filter1=:filter1', function (context) {
        var page = this.params['page'];
        var filter1 = this.params['filter1'];
        var filter2 = $("#chkFilter1").is(':checked');
        var filter3 = $("#chkFilter2").is(':checked');
    });
```

Another option is to ditch the querystring variables and just use a URL structure like this www.something.com#/5/0/1/0/1.  Which would look like this:

```
   this.get('#/:page/:filter1/:filter2/:filter3/:filter4', function (context) {
        var page = this.params['page'];
        var filter1 = this.params['filter1'];
        var filter2 = this.params['filter2'];
        var filter3 = this.params['filter3'];
        var filter4 = this.params['filter4'];
    });
```

Having said all those options, if you have an unknown possible variables you would have to do something more dynamic which is explained here: [sammyjs optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876112/sammyjs-optional-parameters)